# System.FormatException when parsing String to double

Tags: c#, string, parsing, double, exponent

the Code worked fine in Unity. Now I'm using the samecode in a console Project and im getting a **System.FormatException** exception.

The code is:

```
private double ConvertToNumber(string number)
        {      
            return double.Parse(number, numberStyle);
        }
```

parameter when calling are:

```
number = "3.138924e-002"
numberStyle = NumberStyles.AllowExponent | NumberStyles.AllowDecimalPoint | NumberStyles.AllowLeadingSign
```

Does anyone see the Error, or knows what might caus this?

Comment: Can you try changing the return statement to return double.Parse(number);?

Comment: use `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture` in your country decimal separator is `,` not `.`

Comment: `return double.Parse(number, NumberStyles.Any, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The exception is thrown because the string you are providing cannot be converted to a number using the format you specified and **your own current cultrue**. The latter is implict unless you specify it.

If you are reading this value from a database, you should use the invariant culture (i.e. a culture designed to persist numbers and dates in a consistent way in whatever place you need, except user interfaces).

Your code becomes:

```
return double.Parse(number, numberStyle, System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Instead, if you need a specific culture, you need to pass the correct culture in place of the invariant one.

Answer (score 0):

@**Selvin** was right about **CultureInfo.InvariantCulture** adding it as a param fixed the error.

```
return double.Parse(number, numberStyle, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Comment: You should let @Selvin answer the question so they can get credit for it.

Comment: i'm a noob how do i do that ^^?

Comment: Tell them in a comment like I just did.

Comment: Not sure who downvoted this, I think that's a little unfair, but hopefully @Selvin will come back and add their answer. Then you can delete this one.